# Transition based on the position of your window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm asking, I'm not entirely sure is possible...Does anyone know a solution, that when a user scrolls to(and over)and then away from a specific area, a transition happens similar to a hover.

For instance:

-header-
1
2
3
-text-
4
5
6
-footer-

Is it possible, for when the user scrolls to '3' and eventually to 'text' that the actual 'text' transitions from a blurred text to a readable text. As well, when the user scrolls back up or continues down to '4' and '5' it becomes blurred again.

I know you can do the blur transition effect with hovers, but is this possible based solely on window position? And if this is even possible, does it work across browser/mobile?

Comment: Look into parallax scrolling..

Comment: Check out the library waypoints.js for this type of effect. http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/